# Initialize slices of memoryview in cython from numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, cython, memoryview

I am trying to initialize a slice (not not whole) of a memoryview. Suppose that I have memoryview `A` as an attribute of a class (Extension Type)

```
from cython.view cimport array as cvarray

N = 1000
cdef double[:,:,::1] A = cvarray(shape=(2,N,N),itemsize=sizeof(double),format='d')
```

Now, I am trying to initialize it in a `cdef` function. I have no problem initializing the whole memoryview like this

```
# From elsewhere we have loaded a numpy.ndarray B of size (2,N,N)
A[:,:,:] = B
```

This is fine when the initializer `B` is 3D array `(2,N,N)` so that we do not have to *slice* `A`. But now, the problem is here: suppose that I have 2D arrays `B1` and `B2` of size (N,N), and trying to initialize as

```
A[0,:,:] = B1
A[1,:,:] = B2
```

This gives me the following error:

```
TypeError: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
```

Of course I can copy all data one-by-one from `B1` and `B2` to `A`, but this would not be efficient. This process is in a loop and the size `N` is large. `B1` and `B2` come form loading *netcdf* files as `numpy.ndarray` type.

Also, I am defining `A` to be as a *memoryview* so that somewhere else in the code I can use `nogil` functions over accessing `A`.

I am wondering if there is an efficient way to initialize the memoryview as above, or at least, somehow play with pointers of `B1` and `B2` and put them together into an iterable array. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can find two options:

1. It works if you type `B1` and `B2` as a memoryview.
2. You can access the `base` attribute of the memoryview to get the `cvarray` and index that:

   ```
   A.base[0,:,:] = B1
   A.base[1,:,:] = B2
   ```

   I don't think this will necessarily work for all memoryview compatible objects (they are required to define the buffer interface rather than a useful `__getitem__`) but it should work for most of them, including `cvarray`.